# How to toggle and untoggle a specific row and changed its background inside a *ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to toggle and un toggle a specific `<tr>` row inside my table in a *ngFor loop but currently it toggles the whole `<tr>` tag.,

I've already tried applying this on my `<tr>` but other fields could still be toggled/untoggle.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
 <tr
   *ngFor="let repo of repos; let idx = index"
   #tr 
   (click)="tr.classList.toggle('selected')">
```

Expected Result:

Be able to toggle and untoggle my current selection. And if I selected, let say the first row and want to toggle the 2nd row. It should toggle the 2nd row and untoggle the first row.

Actual Output: 
I can highlight toggle and untoggle every row

Comment: You need to map something identifiying each table row to a boolean value instantiated to false. When a row is clicked, set the mapped boolean value to true and make sure all other values are false. Use the map to determine whether or not apply the highlight.

Comment: can you please create a https://stackblitz.com for this

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vimymj

Comment: @ Bryyy I think you have got answer no.. abney317's answer should  solve your problem.

Comment: It still lacks one use case. I also tried that before :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want one row to be selected at a time you could make a variable to store the id of the selected row.

```
<tr *ngFor ="let item of [a,b,c,d]; let idx = index" #tr (click)="selectedRow == idx ? selectedRow = null : selectedRow = idx" [class.selected]="selectedRow == idx">
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
```

and create the variable (if using typescript, something like this):

```
selectedRow: number = null;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyebj4

Comment: Toggle works but I can't untoggle the current selection unless I click on another row. So, basically, it still needs to untoggle the currently selected row without having to click on another row which is another scenario

Comment: Your stackblitz doesn't behave that way.

Comment: Since it's my current solution so it doesn't really behave that way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, but I added a stackblitz link so you can see my example.

Comment: Yes, it works. But it's still missing a use case that's what I meant. Let say you clicked on the first row and you want untoggle it, so you clicked again to remove the color. 

2 ways to untoggle: [1] Click another row [2] Click the selected row again

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {

  items = [{ leter: 'a', selected: false}, { leter: 'b', selected: false}, { leter: 'c', selected: false}, { leter: 'd', selected: false}];

  selectedIndex: number = null;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <tr *ngFor ="let item of items; let i = index" 
    (click)="item.selected = !item.selected; selectedIndex = i" 
    [class.selected]="item.selected && selectedIndex === i">

    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cr4kjk?file=src/app/app.component.html)**